# Renaming post to something else, breaks dashboard if edit_posts is false

Tags: admin-menu

I've been changing the name of the "Posts" to something else with the following code:

```
// Change menu labels
function xxx_admin_menus() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;

    $menu[5][0] = 'Nyheter'; // Change Posts to Nyheter
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Alla nyheter';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Ny nyhet';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'xxx_admin_menus' );
```

This works. However, if a user that logs in does not have the edit_posts capability, the dashboard get's wrecked with error messages.

Is there a better way to change menu item names without this happening?

Comment: Is this solved? It should be, because I'm sure that with the additional check suggested there are no more errors. If so, then you should go on and accept the answer.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 0):

It can not work for user roles that don't see and don't have access to the menu section. It just is not there - for them -, so you can't address it, hence the errors you are getting. Just add a check:

```
if( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) { 
  //code 
}
```